# How to send a large MMS for free from a PC?

Tags: bluetooth, mms

I have a Samsung Gt-B2100i and there is a limit on the MMS size from the OS which is equal to 300ko. I can send 50 Mo with my Mobile network operator.
I often send videos to peoples without internet *(but use the Mobile network operator)*, but I can't send them with my phone since they are usually 2 Mb large *(most of the time)*.

So is there a free on-line service or a software which I can use to send MMS to a French mobile phone?

***Note for software*** : I'm already using my phone to get internet over bluetooth on my PC. There should be a similar software for sending MMS. I don't care about the OS as I can use OSX linux or windows.

Comment: There no supplementary charge on my `Mobile network operator`for sending SMS so I consider it as free.